# What does "when in doubt, lay out" mean?

Tags: idioms

So, what does it mean? "When in doubt, lay out." It seems to be an advice.

Comment: A [google search](http://nashvillemusicianssurvivalmanual.com/Blog/?p=979)  quickly shows it means *don't play anything if you don't know the music.*

Comment: For some reason I can't find it in Google

Comment: click on the link in my comment.

Comment: It could be taken to mean 'Spend your way out of trouble'. The music-scene usage is not mainstream, not being given in the dictionaries I've checked in.

Comment: It could mean it's always better to be sun tanned. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

"Lay out" is not a music-scene usage specifically, it  is a Southern (US) way to say "call in sick" to work/school. I think that is what the linked article in the comments refers to.